# Powershell Pipeline Property Binding Failing

Tags: powershell, binding, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I'm running into a peculiar issue which I'm unable to figure out.  I'm attempting to bind the value from `Get-ADUser -Identity Test-User -Property SamAccountName` to a custom built cmdlet.  This is something I've done many times before, but for some weird reason it's failing now.  To reduce complexity I wrote a test function to minimize complexity.  That function is:

```
function Test-Binding{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [Alias("SamAccountName")]
        [string]
        $Identity
    )

    return $Identity
}
```

When executing `Get-ADUser -Identity Test-user | Test-Binding` I get the error:

```
Test-Binding : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:76
+ Trace-Command parameterbinding -Expression {Get-ADUser -Identity Test-User | Test- ...
+                                                                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (CN=Test-User...,DC=contoso,DC=com:PSObject) [Test-Binding], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Test-Binding
```

My next step, after reviewing my code and looking at previous successful scripts was to run a trace.  In the trace the binding is successful in the first attempt, however `powershell` then tries to continue binding it to other input values until it craps out.  Here's the dump:

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Get-ADUser]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Get-ADUser]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     DYNAMIC parameter object: [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUserParameterSet]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND NAMED args to DYNAMIC parameters
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Test-User] to parameter [Identity]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Trying to convert argument value from System.String to Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT arg type to param type using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT SUCCESSFUL using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo: [Test-User]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ValidateNotNullOrEmptyADEntityAttribute
]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Executing VALIDATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ValidateNotNullAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             BIND arg [Test-User] to param [Identity] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND POSITIONAL args to DYNAMIC parameters
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Get-ADUser]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Test-Binding]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Test-Binding]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Binding]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [] to parameter [Identity]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [] to param [Identity] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Test-Binding]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Identity] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] to parameter [Identity]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] to param [Identity] SKIPPED
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Identity] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName WITH COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection] to parameter [Identity]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         ERROR: Argument cannot be an empty string
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Out-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Out-LineOutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ConsoleLineOutput] to parameter [LineOutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Object]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ConsoleLineOutput] to param [LineOutput] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Out-LineOutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Out-LineOutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-LineOutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [out-lineoutput]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Format-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Format-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Format-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Format-Default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.] to parameter [InputObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.] to param [InputObject] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [format-default]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAt
tribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAt
tribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAt
tribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [1] to parameter [Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing DATA GENERATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ArgumentToVersionTransformationAt
tribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             result returned from DATA GENERATION: 1.0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Version]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetStrictModeCommand+ValidateVersionAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [1.0] to param [Version] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-StrictMode]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
Test-Binding : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:76
+ Trace-Command parameterbinding -Expression {Get-ADUser -Identity Test-User | Test- ...
+                                                                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (CN=Walter Kerce...,DC=contoso,DC=com:PSObject) [Test-Binding], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Test-Binding

DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

My goal is to understand why this binding is failing in this instance.

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate as I'm not working with $null returns.

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked question points out exactly why this is behaving as it is. You can test this with your `Get-ADUser` calls as well. It's not about `Get-ADUser` returning `$null`, it's that the `Identity` property will be added dynamically to the returned object with a value of `$null`, rather than just being missing. Because it is exists, it is bound to the pipeline input and the alias never gets used.

Comment: @briantist actually, it doesn't.  If you follow the breadcrumbs the claim is that you'll run into an issue when the input is $null data.  As I said in my edit, I'm not working with $null inputs.

Comment: The input to your function *is* `$null` because you are using `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`. PowerShell tries to use the actual parameter name first (`Identity`). Normally, that would be *missing*, and it would go on to binding the aliases. However in the case of the AD cmdlets, what will happen instead is that *any* property name requested will be be dynamically generated with a value of `$null` if it doesn't already exist. That dynamic property is then bound, and therefore aliases are never checked.

Comment: @briantist As I stated in my question and as is observable in the output from the debug, powershell is able to recognize the match.  This is the 2nd time you've commented without reading fully what you're commenting on.  I'll no longer reply to your comments.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have fully read what I'm commenting on. I think the `Trace-Command` output supports what I'm saying (which incidentally is the same thing stated in the answer you've accepted, and in the linked duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately a known issue with the AD cmdlets -- if you ask an object generated by the AD cmdlets for a property it doesn't have, it automatically generates on and gives it a $null value instead of correctly returning that the property does not exist, which would allow the parameter binding to continue and get the correct value.

You can see the Microsoft Connect item about this [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/653795/adcomputer-object-generates-empty-dynamic-properties).

The only workaround I've seen is to name the parameter in your function after the exact property name used by the AD object, and alias other names. I often have to name my parameters DNSHostName, for example, with an alias of ComputerName, if I want to be able to pipe Get-ADComputer to it.

Comment: I would also add that another work around would be to use code like this:  `Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select SamAccountName | Test-Binding`